# Why is it possible to ignore gamma factor in uniformly accelerated motion in SR?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration

I have a doubt on one step of the derivation of the hyperbolic relations between $t$ and $\tau$ and $x$ and $\tau$ for uniformly accelerated frames in one dimension.

They come from $2$ differential equations:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}U^0}{\mathrm{d}\tau}&=aU^1 \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}U^1}{\mathrm{d}\tau}&=aU^0
\end{align}
$$

That are valid if **a**$^2$ = a$^2$. ('**a**' being the 4-vector for acceleration, and 'a' the local acceleration observed for any object in the accelerated frame)

But that statement is true only when $v = 0$, that is, when the inertial frame has momentarily the same speed of the accelerated one.

Of course, there will always be a comoving inertial frame for which **a**$^2$ = a$^2$.

And it is true that any inertial frame is as good as any other to do the maths in SR. But if one is choosed, as I understand, it must be kept all the way.

In that case how can I ignore the term $\gamma^6$, (containing $v$ as a variable), in the equation: **a**$^2$ = $\gamma^6$a$^2$?

Comment: *how can I ignore the term $\gamma^6$* Your question would be less confusing if you showed the equation with $\gamma^6$ that you are referring to.

Comment: @G. Smith OK. I added the equation.

Comment: Factors like $\gamma^6$ occur if you're trying to find the acceleration four-vector from the velocity and acceleration three-vectors. But there is no reason to use those three-vectors here. The norm of the acceleration four-vector is simply the proper acceleration.

Comment: @ Ben Crowell I think I understood. The numerical value of 'a' is the proper **and** coordinate acceleration for a comoving frame. After that, the coordinate acceleration decreases (otherwise the speed would increase boundless). But when multiplied by the mentioned factor, it stays the same. So, it is a constant in the differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

> if one is choosed, as I understand, it must be kept all the way.

Not in this case. The concept of [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) involves an instantaneously comoving inertial frame in which the instantaneous acceleration is measured. Without a continuous sequence of different inertial frames, each comoving with the accelerating object at faster and faster speeds, *constant* proper acceleration has no meaning.